# spring session redirect after timeout

Tags: spring, redirect, session-timeout

I have configured spring security for login form. Everything works fine except session timeout. 
When session timeouts I want to redirect to login page. Instead I am redirected to homepage. Below is part of my security xml .Can anyone suggest anything via xml configuration

```
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
        <!-- This settings is for IE. Default this setting is on migrateSession. 
            When IE tries to migrate the session, the auth cookie does not migrate, resulting 
            in a nice login screen again, after you've logged in. This setting ensures 
            that the session will not be invalidated, and thus IE will still work as 
            expected. -->
        <session-management session-fixation-protection="none" />

        <intercept-url pattern="/login.jsp" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/css/*" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/img/**" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/js/**" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/lib/**" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/fonts/**" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />


        <form-login login-page="/login.jsp" login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check"
            default-target-url="/index.html" always-use-default-target="true"
            authentication-failure-url="/login?error=true" username-parameter="username"
            password-parameter="password" authentication-failure-handler-ref="authenticationFailureHandler" />
        <logout logout-success-url="/login.jsp" logout-url="/j_spring_security_logout" invalidate-session="true" />
        <session-management>
            <concurrency-control max-sessions="1"  />
        </session-management>
        <session-management invalid-session-url="/login.jsp" />
        <!-- disable csrf protection -->
        <csrf disabled="true" />
    </http>
```

I have added timeout in web.xml as

```
<session-config>
        <session-timeout>1</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
```

Comment: Can you change your session-management tag as : **<session-management><concurrency-control error-if-maximum-exceeded="true" expired-url="/login.jsp" max-sessions="1">/concurrency-control></session-management>**

Comment: Still same problem...its not working.